# Listview shows duplicated items when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I am wondering about this problem that I am encountering in Android.

I populate the `ArrayAdapter` from `ArrayList`. The entries are fine and unique but when I scroll down the `listview` it keeps reading the existing elements.

How can I avoid this?

Here is my code.

```
ArrayList<String> channelname = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_channels);

      listchannels();

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylistchannel,R.id.Channelname,channelname);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void listchannels()
{
      InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(testFile.getReadStream());
      BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

      do {
            key = buffreader.readLine();
            if(key != null)
                value = buffreader.readLine();
            channelname.add(key);                
      } while (key != null && value != null);
}
```

Comment: You probably add them multiple times here `channelname.add(key);`. Look over your logic.

Comment: Well, the Listview is filled fine with unique items. I get duplicate items when i scroll down and up.

Comment: Does your implementation use the view holder pattern to reuse the views? Maybe you are doing something wrong there. Or maybe you parse the data with duplications. In each case would help you to implement and call the getCount, getItem and getItemId methods that you override inside the adapter. Also, before you set the list to the adapter, print the size of the list. It must be the same with the size inside the adapter. You have to post the code of your adapter class .

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that I put together and tested on a phone and works great, modify it to fit your need, I added a listView to my layout file,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >
</ListView>
```

Then I added a new layout xml file that defines the content of each item in the list view, I called it channelinfo.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/channel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Channel"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code in my activity that invokes and populate the listView with a list of items,

```
ArrayList<String> channelname = new ArrayList<String>();
  channelname.add("Test1");
  channelname.add("Test2");
  channelname.add("Test3");
  channelname.add("Test4");
  channelname.add("Test5");
  channelname.add("Test6");

  final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  ChannelAdapter cAdapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, channelname);
  listView.setAdapter(cAdapter);

private class ChannelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  ArrayList<String> channelname;
  public ChannelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> channelname) {
    super  (context, R.layout.activity_fullscreen, channelname);
    this.channelname = channelname;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
      if(convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channelinfo,parent, false);
      }  
      String  name = getItem(position);
      TextView txtview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channel);
      txtview.setText(name);
      return convertView;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return channelname.size();
  }

  @Override
  public String getItem(int position) {
    return channelname.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey faljbour. Thanks for the help. I wanted to ask should i make an instance of this ChannelAdapter class in the Oncreate()? Can you show me how to make the instance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure, let me add it to the answer

Comment: The code is good! But for a reason i get blank items! Any idea why?

Comment: see if there is an exception is being thrown in the catch(Exception e) area of the getView method, put a break point there.

Comment: no sorry, I have a typo in the code, the construtor, let me fix it, rename the <videolist> to <channelname>   this  line >>> super  (context, R.layout.fileinfo2, videoList);  sorry about that, it is my error

Comment: Yep, i changed that and at the top the <VideoInfo> to <String>. The Listview is filled but the rows are empty. In my previous implementation ArrayAdapter<String> cAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylistchannel,R.id.Channelname,channelname); i have reference to the TextView Channelname. Should we put this Channelname reference to the custom Class?

Comment: yes, please update the R.id with the correct layout id, I fixed the class reference to videoInfo, sorry I cut this from code that works just fine listing a list of videos,

Comment: please copy the updated answer one more time, i fixed all of the issues.

Comment: faljbour the code is working now, but the problem is that with this new Class i don't access the Textview ID within the Listview Item which is Channelname. I think that's why the Item is populated but the text is not shown in the Listview Items. Any idea how to implement this? Here is the code from the previous ArrayAdapter new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylistchannel,R.id.Channelname,channelname);

Comment: sure, I guess you would need to add a new layout file (xml) that describes the content of the each list view item, then reference it in the getView method, let me modify the code and add the xml file content

Comment: faljbour! I still get blank Items. I think it has something to do with the Textview. It needs to populate the textview of every item on the listview from the ArrayList. I cannot figure out from the CustomAdapter.

Comment: @kanun, sorry for the delay, I think we are missing one line for code that was in your original code,  setListAdapter(cAdapter); it should be after you instantiate your ChannelAdapter

Comment: faljbour, yes i have done that before! I don't know but i still get blank items after the code. I am bit confused right now!

Comment: @kanun, I just added a complete example that I tested and it works just fine, please copy the code and modify it to fit your need

Comment: faljbour, the code works like a charm. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot man!